# "Failed to execute DbAction.DeleteRoot" with JDBC?

Tags: kotlin, spring-jdbc

I have a JDBC repository with a "deleteItem" method, however when I trigger the method via Postman, I get a strange error: "Failed to execute DbAction.DeleteRoot"

Some items delete without issue, only a subset of the data is triggering this bug.

Here's the extent of my @Repository code:

```
@Repository
interface ItemRepository: CrudRepository<Item, UUID>
{
    @Query( "select * from item_data where scopes @> :scopes")
    fun findItemsByScope(@Param("scopes") scope: String): List<Item>
}
```

And here's the @Component that implements it (and is called by my API)

```
@Component
class RepositoryItemPersistenceAdapter(
        private val repository: ItemRepository
){

    fun getItemsByScope(scope: String) : List<Item> =
       repository.findItemsByScope(scope)

    fun deleteItem(id: UUID) = repository.deleteById(id)

    fun getAllItems(): List<Item> = repository.findAll()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem ultimately turned out not to be code-based, but rather schema-based!

The Item database ID was used as a foreign key in two other databases. Trying to delete the Item by ID threw an error because it would have orphaned the rows in the other tables when the foreign key stopped referring to anything.

The exception details (which aren't returned as part of the 500) were as follows:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table
>   "item_data" violates foreign key constraint
>   "identity_mapping_id_fkey" on table
>   "identity_mapping"   Detail: Key
>   (id)=(99304a5d-5bcc-4f31-a192-625ed8c9059b) is still referenced from
>   table "identity_mapping".

This is also why some of the data deleted just fine -- it had no corresponding entries in the mapping table, so it didn't trigger this error during a delete.

The ultimate solution is to check for foreign keys before deleting, either removing or updating the corresponding rows before you do.